# change logo OpenSearch dashboards - kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

Need to change OpenSearch logo in the dashboard.

[image]

Found i way to change if I run it **local host or using docker changing the opensearch_dashboards.yml**. But how could i change it if i hosted this in **AWS**? Not locally or using a docker.

Reference link: [https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/branding/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20OpenSearch%20Dashboards%20uses,by%20including%20a%20custom%20opensearch_dashboards](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/branding/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20OpenSearch%20Dashboards%20uses,by%20including%20a%20custom%20opensearch_dashboards).